# Converting Outlook time to string

Tags: python, datetime, time, win32com

I am using win32com to parse outlooks msg files on my hard drive.  Everything is working except the sent date.  I have the list of emails in a wxPython list box and when you click on an email I want to populate the date in a text box. When I try to convert the msg.SentOn from time type to string type I get a TypeError.  I believe it is looking for a timestamp and I am not sure how to get there from Pytime.

```
def onListBox(self, event):

    attachList = []
    self.attachList.Clear()
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    self.email = event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()
    if self.toFrom == 0:
        fileName = "C:\Users\onp1ldy\Desktop\EMAILS\emails_Sent\\" + self.email
    else:
        fileName = "C:\Users\onp1ldy\Desktop\EMAILS\emails\\" + self.email
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(fileName)
    #print msg.SenderName
    #print msg.SenderEmailAddress
    print type(msg.SentOn)
    print msg.SentOn
    newDate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', msg.SentOn)
    print newDate
```

Output:

```
<type 'time'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 181, in onListBox
12/04/17 20:43:49
    newDate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', msg.SentOn)
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not time
```

Can someone help with this conversion?

Comment: *"I get a strange tuple"* but you did assign `newDate` to a tuple of `(time.strftime, msg.SentOn)`.  What did you expect? You probably meant to do this instead? `newDate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', msg.SentOn)`

Comment: You are correct, I did mean to do that.  That was a copy paste issue that I missed. I updated the code with the new TypeError.

Comment: If you're looking for the `str` of `msg.SentOn` in the same format, could you not just `newDate = str(msg.SentOn)`?

Comment: Since `msg.SentOn` appears to be an instance of [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects), I think you want [`msg.SentOn.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime)

Comment: I just found something on time from win32com objects.  The only way I could get it converted was with `newDate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(msg.SentOn)))`  . The `int` returns an integer compatible with the standard Python time module.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found [Pytime](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyTime.html). This showed the conversion of pytime to an int that is compatible with the time module.

```
time.strftime("%#c", time.localtime(int(timeObject)))
```